# Using an existing Photoshop Design file in Eclipse ADT

Tags: java, android, user-interface, photoshop, eclipse-adt

Very new to UI development on Android apart from using the default buttons and so on from Eclipse ADT. I have a designer creating designs for different activities in Photoshop. How exactly can I take those .PSD files and use them in Eclipse to make this template/design fully functional in a Android app? So basically how can I take a PSD file and implement it onto an activity and add events handlers and so on to different layers/elements of the design file?

Like I said, I'm very new to this sort of UI development so I may not be on the right direction on how this process works.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not implement psd file into android layout file. 
You have to take different images from psd from your designer and you can set them according to the design.

for example if in psd background is some picture, you should use that picture file as background in your root element.

you should ask your designer for separate images from psd file....
Hope this helps :)